# Knife tool won't go away

Tags: knife-tool

I'm pretty new to blender but I've nearly got the hang of it. Unfortunately, I keep running into the same problem: whenever I use the knife tool, it won't go away! No shortcuts are working and I can't click on any other tool - it just makes a new line in the workspace below the sidebar. I used to be able to quit blender and reopen it, but now that I'm working on one project, every time I reopen the project, the knife tool is already in action and I can't do anything.

Is this a glitch or am I just missing something really obvious? Any help appreciated:)

Comment: This is one of those obvious dumb ones, but did you try pressing Esc?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Oh my god. I feel like such an idiot!!! Thank you so much!!! I hope you have a lovely rest of your day:)